I am using the YOLOv5 model provided by Ultralytics in PyTorch. How can I see which images the model is struggling with?
This is the YOLOv5 implementation I am talking about and this is the file I am using to test the model.
For some classes, it performing decently enough. However, for the rest of the classes, it is not doing a great job. I would like to see the type of images where the model struggles.
How can I get the name of the images or the file paths?
I tried running this file with the --save-txt parameter but I do not understand its meaning.
Thank you!

To be able to track the learning of a model I recommend environments like ClearML.  ClearML allows you to see real-time results on some images while model learning
Yolov5 allows you to integrate them without any problem for example here.
Regarding --save-txt; on val.py save the validation results to a .txt file 
To default you can see your output into yolov5/runs/val/exp--

Thank you for your answer. However, this was not the type of answer I was expecting... Could you please explain what the results of -save-txt mean, are they the predicted labels and bounding boxes? I am sorry if this is a naive question :P

With --save-txt you will visualize the labels and corresponding class.
For example:
Your model recognizes two classes (person, cat)
In one frame you have these labels
1 0.733508 0.249939 0.495952 0.497498
Where 1 is the class (cat) and the other numbers represent the bounding box position:
0.733508 0.249939 ([x,y] Top-Left Point)
0.495952 0.497498 ([x,y] Bottom-right)

Okay, thank you, these are the outputs of the model, right? I can compare them to the ground truth labels to find the differences, right?

Of course, if you need it, I remind you that you can use detect.py with a custom image to obtain more accurate results on your model and image.
If you are new to yolov5 and in computer vision, I suggest this robloflow guide for beginners on yolov5:
https://blog.roboflow.com/yolov5-improvements-and-evaluation/

Awesome, detect.py is what I was looking for! Now, all I need are summary metrics like overall precision and recall at the end of detect.py's output...

For these, you can see the loss curve (less is better) and the precision curve (high is better), but from what I see you need to learn more info about these metrics, than this, you can check the f1 score and the other metrics.
Another thing, this is out of context from this post, please If I answered your previous problem, set it like solved, and open a new one

Thank you for all your help, Degik. I have accepted your answer but you have technically not solved my query... I wanted to know the way in which I could see the file names of the incorrect predictions. I would be grateful if you could tell me this.

When you get the labels you have always the prediction correct or with error, it depends from the model if recognised the class on frame.
What can help is set the confidence --conf-thres.
Another aspect you need to consider is the loss value, there are always an error on the prediction, if you will compare your label predicted with the truth you can check yourself are not perfect
